# Создание товара через WC rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Добрый день. Делаю POST запрос на endpoint **/wp-json/wc/v2/products/** с JSON описанием товара.

JSON генерирую по примеру из документации; единственное отличие - мой **stock_quantity** не *integer*, а *float* (вот такой приходит, надо записать float).

Естественно возвращается ошибка 401.

Как избежать подобной коллизии? Может, стоит применить какой-нибудь хук/или переписать какую-нибудь функцию?

Comment: А на самом сайте включены float quantities? Если нет, то вот ссылка: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417718/woocommerce-decimal-quantity

Comment: Да, в админке добавление величин с запятой работает, на фронте эти величины так же работают. Дело в rest-api, который требует чтобы quantity был всегда только integer.